# Basic loop question including while and for

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I couldn't understand that why i equals 3 here.The condition part in for loop works for n1=4 n2=2 and n1=3 n2=3.Shouldn't i equal to 2? A detailed,step by step explanation would really help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n1 = 4;
    int n2 = 2;
    int i = 0;
    while (n2 <= 4) {
        for (; n1 >= n2; n1--)
            i++;
    n2++;
    }
    System.out.println(i);
    System.out.println(n2 + " " + n1);
}
```

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, did you try debugging?

Comment: Your for loop does nothing useful. Did you intend the ```i++;``` statement to be in that loop? The ```while``` statement means you go round that loop three times. You increment ```i``` every time round that loop.

Answer (score 2):

When your code executes while loop first time it directly gets into for loop and increase value of i three time. Because your for loop executes until n1 becomes lower then n2.

First step of for loop

```
4 >= 2 (n1 >= n2)
    increase i (i becomes 1)
    loop decreases n1 (n1 becomes 3)
3 >= 2 (n1 >= n2)
    increase i (i becomes 2)
    loop decreases n1 (n1 becomes 2)
2 >= 2 (n1 >= n2)
    increase i (i becomes 3)
    loop decreases n1 (n1 becomes 1)
```

it gets out for loop when n1 becomes 1. Second iteration in your while loop, it does not gets into for loop because n1 is lower then n2.

So your variable i has value 3.

Answer (score 0):

If it was: `for (; n1 > n2; n1--)` then i would be 2